# Python Multiprocessing.Pool lazy iteration

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm wondering about the way that python's Multiprocessing.Pool class works with map, imap, and map_async.  My particular problem is that I want to map on an iterator that creates memory-heavy objects, and don't want all these objects to be generated into memory at the same time.  I wanted to see if the various map() functions would wring my iterator dry, or intelligently call the next() function only as child processes slowly advanced, so I hacked up some tests as such:

```
def g():
  for el in xrange(100):
    print el
    yield el

def f(x):
  time.sleep(1)
  return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
  go = g()
  g2 = pool.imap(f, go)
  g2.next()
```

And so on with map, imap, and map_async.  This is the most flagrant example however, as simply calling next() a single time on g2 prints out all my elements from my generator g(), whereas if imap were doing this 'lazily' I would expect it to only call go.next() once, and therefore print out only '1'.

Can someone clear up what is happening, and if there is some way to have the process pool 'lazily' evaluate the iterator as needed?

Thanks,

Gabe

Comment: After removing the `time.sleep` call and adding a `print os.getpid(), x` in `f` the behavior looks even more weird, sometimes only 2 or 3 different PID's are printed and always do a different amount of iterations... BTW what Python version are you using?

Comment: Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
Standard debian install.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let's look at the end of the program first.

The multiprocessing module uses `atexit` to call `multiprocessing.util._exit_function` when your program ends.

If you remove `g2.next()`, your program ends quickly.

The `_exit_function` eventually calls `Pool._terminate_pool`. The main thread changes the state of `pool._task_handler._state` from `RUN` to `TERMINATE`. Meanwhile the `pool._task_handler` thread is looping in `Pool._handle_tasks` and bails out when it reaches the condition

```
            if thread._state:
                debug('task handler found thread._state != RUN')
                break
```

(See /usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py)

This is what stops the task handler from fully consuming your generator, `g()`. If you look in `Pool._handle_tasks` you'll see

```
        for i, task in enumerate(taskseq):
            ...
            try:
                put(task)
            except IOError:
                debug('could not put task on queue')
                break
```

This is the code which consumes your generator. (`taskseq` is not exactly your generator, but as `taskseq` is consumed, so is your generator.)

In contrast, when you call `g2.next()` the main thread calls `IMapIterator.next`, and waits when it reaches `self._cond.wait(timeout)`.

That the main thread is waiting instead of
calling `_exit_function` is what allows the task handler thread to run normally, which means fully consuming the generator as it `put`s tasks in the `worker`s' `inqueue` in the `Pool._handle_tasks` function.

The bottom line is that all `Pool` map functions consume the entire iterable that it is given. If you'd like to consume the generator in chunks, you could do this instead:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools
import time


def g():
    for el in xrange(50):
        print el
        yield el


def f(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    go = g()
    result = []
    N = 11
    while True:
        g2 = pool.map(f, itertools.islice(go, N))
        if g2:
            result.extend(g2)
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            break
    print(result)
```

Comment: Great answer, I ended up re-implementing a thread pool that consumes element by element in the meantime, but your islice solution would have been much less work for me, oh well :-).  I tried looking around pool.py some and noticed that indeed the map/imap/map_async functions seemed to eat up the iterator right away.  It's not clear to me if that really necessary though, especially in the case of standard Pool.map()?

Comment: @Gabe: To consume the iterator just-in-time, I think some extra signaling mechanism would have to be coded in `Pool` to tell the task handler when to `put` more tasks in the `inqueue`. Maybe it's possible, but doesn't currently exist in `Pool`, and might slow the process down a bit too.

Comment: Indeed, my solution was to make a task queue of size N*size_of_pool and play around with N until it looked like the queue was keeping a good buffer.  Of course this is task-dependent so I can understand that the author of the Pool code didn't want to deal with that. Thanks for your response!

Comment: What if the generator is such that you don't know the number of elements (100 in this case)?

Comment: @Vince: You could change the `for-loop` to a `while-loop`, and break when the result of `pool.map` is empty. I've edited the post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is implemented in the [NuMap](https://mcieslik-mctp.github.io/papy/api.html#numap-numap) package, from the website:

> NuMap is a parallel (thread- or process-based, local or remote),
>   buffered, multi-task, itertools.imap or multiprocessing.Pool.imap
>   function replacement. Like imap it evaluates a function on elements of
>   a sequence or iterable, and it does so lazily. 
>   Laziness can be adjusted via the “stride” and “buffer” arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and was disappointed to learn that map consumes all its elements. I coded a function which consumes the iterator lazily using the Queue data type in multiprocessing. This is similar to what @unutbu describes in a comment to his answer but as he points out, suffers from having no callback mechanism for re-loading the Queue. The Queue datatype instead exposes a timeout parameter and I've used 100 milliseconds to good effect.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count
from Queue import Full as QueueFull
from Queue import Empty as QueueEmpty

def worker(recvq, sendq):
    for func, args in iter(recvq.get, None):
        result = func(*args)
        sendq.put(result)

def pool_imap_unordered(function, iterable, procs=cpu_count()):
    # Create queues for sending/receiving items from iterable.

    sendq = Queue(procs)
    recvq = Queue()

    # Start worker processes.

    for rpt in xrange(procs):
        Process(target=worker, args=(sendq, recvq)).start()

    # Iterate iterable and communicate with worker processes.

    send_len = 0
    recv_len = 0
    itr = iter(iterable)

    try:
        value = itr.next()
        while True:
            try:
                sendq.put((function, value), True, 0.1)
                send_len += 1
                value = itr.next()
            except QueueFull:
                while True:
                    try:
                        result = recvq.get(False)
                        recv_len += 1
                        yield result
                    except QueueEmpty:
                        break
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    # Collect all remaining results.

    while recv_len < send_len:
        result = recvq.get()
        recv_len += 1
        yield result

    # Terminate worker processes.

    for rpt in xrange(procs):
        sendq.put(None)
```

This solution has the advantage of not batching requests to Pool.map. One individual worker can not block others from making progress. YMMV. Note that you may want to use a different object to signal termination for the workers. In the example, I've used None.

Tested on "Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"

Comment: I've checked on Python 3.3 and neither `imap` nor `imap_unordered` does not consume all the arguments before kicking off the mapped function, although `map` does.

Comment: +1 This is nearly what I need, but unfortunately I need ordered results.

Comment: Instead of tuning get/put timeouts for in/out Queues, I normally 1) set a fixed size for both Queues, and 2) let get/put block if the Queue is empty/full.

This way there is no need to tune timeouts. There is only the need to check the number of items going into the in-queue and out of the out-queue.

The correct order is then: 1) start workers; 2) start out-Queue collector; 3) iterate over input and populate the in-Queue.

Comment: @neo, it is possible to get ordered results, too. The way to achieve this is to have 4 limited-size Queues [In (data for workers), Out (final, properly ordered results), Serial (keeps track of items in processing), Sort (intermediate Queue)] and 2 types of workers - a single `sorter()` and N actual workers. The idea is: 1) have a `serial` number generator; 2) submit each dataset as `In.put( (serial, data) )`, together with `Serial.put(serial)`; 3) workers do `Sort.put((serial, result))`; 4) `sorter()` gets items from Sort, sorts them by `serial`, and puts into Out.

Comment: @neo, here's an untested example of `sorter()`: https://bitbucket.org/qmentis/bioinformatics-scripts/src/333a2d67f7931e2e44142298f64a9d1bc7ce7b59/sliding-window-polyA-trimmer.py?at=master#cl-154 Forgot to mention that all Queues must have the same size limit, and all queue items are assumed to take approximately the same amount of processing time for this scheme to work (otherwise the `sorter()`'s internal buffer will start accumulating too many results).

Answer (score 1):

In this example (see code, please) 2 workers.

Pool work as expected: when worker is free, then to do next iteration.

This code as code in topic, except one thing: argument size = 64 k.

64 k - default socket buffer size.

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep


def f( x ):
    print( "f()" )
    sleep( 3 )
    return x


def get_reader():
    for x in range( 10 ):
        print( "readed: ", x )
        value = " " * 1024 * 64 # 64k
        yield value


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Pool( processes=2 )

    data = p.imap( f, get_reader() )

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, and came to a different solution than the other answers here so I figured I would share it.

```
import collections, multiprocessing

def map_prefetch(func, data, lookahead=128, workers=16, timeout=10):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(workers) as pool:
        q = collections.deque()
        for x in data:
            q.append(pool.apply_async(func, (x,)))
            if len(q) >= lookahead:
                yield q.popleft().get(timeout=timeout)
        while len(q):
            yield q.popleft().get(timeout=timeout)

for x in map_prefetch(myfunction, huge_data_iterator):
    # do stuff with x
```

Basically is uses a queue to send at most `lookahead` pending requests to the worker pool, enforcing a limit on buffered results. The work starts asap within that limit so it can run in parallel. Also the result remains in order.