# multiprocessing.Pool: When to use apply, apply_async or map?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have not seen clear examples with use-cases for [Pool.apply](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply), [Pool.apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) and [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map). I am mainly using `Pool.map`; what are the advantages of others?

Answer (score 556, accepted):

Back in the old days of Python, to call a function with arbitrary arguments, you would use `apply`:

```
apply(f,args,kwargs)
```

`apply` still exists in Python2.7 though not in Python3, and is generally not used anymore. Nowadays,

```
f(*args,**kwargs)
```

is preferred. The `multiprocessing.Pool` modules tries to provide a similar interface.

`Pool.apply` is like Python `apply`, except that the function call is performed in a separate process. `Pool.apply` blocks until the function is completed.

`Pool.apply_async` is also like Python's built-in `apply`, except that the call returns immediately instead of waiting for the result. An `AsyncResult` object is returned. You call its `get()` method to retrieve the result of the function call. The `get()` method blocks until the function is completed. Thus, `pool.apply(func, args, kwargs)` is equivalent to `pool.apply_async(func, args, kwargs).get()`.

In contrast to `Pool.apply`, the `Pool.apply_async` method also has a callback which, if supplied, is called when the function is complete. This can be used instead of calling `get()`.

For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo_pool(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    return x*x

result_list = []
def log_result(result):
    # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
    # result_list is modified only by the main process, not the pool workers.
    result_list.append(result)

def apply_async_with_callback():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(foo_pool, args = (i, ), callback = log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async_with_callback()
```

may yield a result such as

```
[1, 0, 4, 9, 25, 16, 49, 36, 81, 64]
```

Notice, unlike `pool.map`, the order of the results may not correspond to the order in which the `pool.apply_async` calls were made.

---

So, if you need to run a function in a separate process, but want the current process to **block** until that function returns, use `Pool.apply`. Like `Pool.apply`, `Pool.map` blocks until the complete result is returned.

If you want the Pool of worker processes to perform many function calls asynchronously, use `Pool.apply_async`. The **order** of the results is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of the calls to `Pool.apply_async`.

Notice also that you could call a number of **different** functions with `Pool.apply_async` (not all calls need to use the same function).

In contrast, `Pool.map` applies the same function to many arguments.
However, unlike `Pool.apply_async`, the results are returned in an order corresponding to the order of the arguments.

Comment: Should there be `if __name__=="__main__"` before `apply_async_with_callback()` on Windows?

Comment: Thanks a lot. how about map_async?

Comment: Look inside [multiprocessing/pool.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ea421c534305/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#l245) and you will see that `Pool.map(func,iterable)` is equivalent to `Pool.map_async(func,iterable).get()`. So the relationship between `Pool.map` and `Pool.map_async` is similar to that of `Pool.apply` and `Pool.apply_async`. The `async` commands return immediately, while the non-`async` commands block. The `async` commands also have a callback.

Comment: Deciding between using `Pool.map` and `Pool.apply` is similar to deciding when to use `map` or `apply` in Python. You just use the tool that fits the job. Deciding between using the `async` and non-`async` version depends on if you want the call to block the current process and/or if you want to use the callback.

Comment: callback sounds more truly async! i gonna test it out!

Comment: Is the order guarenteed if you use a list comprehension like [this example in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)? e.g.  `multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) for i in range(4)]`
    `print [res.get(timeout=1) for res in multiple_results]`

Comment: @falsePockets: Yes. Each call to `apply_async` returns an `ApplyResult` object. Calling that `ApplyResult`'s `get` method will return the associated function's return value (or raise `mp.TimeoutError` if the call times-out.) So if you put the `ApplyResult`s in an ordered list, then calling their `get` methods will return the results in the same order. You could just use `pool.map` in this situation however.

Comment: Thanks. I considered pool.map, but I want to use a `for` loop instead of list comprehension to set up the arguments to each process, since I'm passing multiple arguments to each process. Some arguments are unique to each process, some are constant among all, and some are constant among only a subset of all processes. Using starmap and others gets quite messy for this case. Also, I want it to work in both python 2 and 3.

Comment: @unutbu I want to run a function in the background but I have some resource limitations and cannot run the function as many times that I want and want to queue the extra executions of the function. Do you have any idea on how I should do that? I have my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49081260/executing-a-function-in-the-background-while-using-limited-number-of-cores-threa). Could you please take a look at my question and see if you can give me some hints (or even better, an answer) on how I should do that?

Comment: If we use `callback` in `pool.apply_async ` as in this example, do we have guarantee of writing protection on the shared variable `result_list`?

Comment: @galactica: Each time the worker function ends successfully (without raising an exception), the callback function is called *in the main process*.
The worker functions put return values in a queue, and the `pool._result_handler` thread in the main process handles the returned values one at a time, passing the returned value to the callback function. So you are guaranteed that the callback function will be called once for each returned value and there is no concurrency problem here because the callback is being called sequentially by a single thread in the main process.

Comment: @galactica: The only caveat is that you need call `pool.join()` before inspecting `result_list` or else it might not contain all the results. (After all, `pool.join()` is telling the main process to wait until all the tasks have finished.)

Comment: @galactica: `result_list` is not a shared variable. Although it may exist in the worker processes, it is only meant to be modified and accessed by the main process. If you do modify `result_list` in a worker process, the value will not be seen by the main process.

Comment: @unutbu, thanks for the detailed clarification! Concerns relieved. This callback based approach seems easier to aggregate results from multiple worker processes.  One thing I noticed is the restriction of only being able to pass one parameter to callback function. Thus, it seems I can't place this callback function and the result list as class members, but only place them as global ones. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @galatica: [It is possible](https://ideone.com/FaWOoQ) to make the callback and `result_list` members of a class.  In the linked example, `foo.log_result` is what is called a *bound method*.
Accessing `foo.log_result` returns a function with the instance `foo` "bound" to it, 
in the sense that calling `foo.log_result(x)` is equivalent to `Foo.log_result(foo, x)`. Notice that `foo` gets passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 180):

Here is an overview in a table format in order to show the differences between `Pool.apply`, `Pool.apply_async`, `Pool.map` and `Pool.map_async`. When choosing one, you have to take multi-args, concurrency, blocking, and ordering into account:

```
                  | Multi-args   Concurrence    Blocking     Ordered-results
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Pool.map          | no           yes            yes          yes
Pool.map_async    | no           yes            no           yes
Pool.apply        | yes          no             yes          no
Pool.apply_async  | yes          yes            no           no
Pool.starmap      | yes          yes            yes          yes
Pool.starmap_async| yes          yes            no           no
```

## Notes:

- `Pool.imap` and `Pool.imap_async` – lazier version of map and map_async.
- `Pool.starmap` method, very much similar to map method besides it acceptance of multiple arguments.
- `Async` methods submit all the processes at once and retrieve the results once they are finished. Use get method to obtain the results.
- `Pool.map`(or `Pool.apply`)methods are very much similar to Python built-in map(or apply). They block the main process until all the processes complete and return the result.

## Examples:

#### map

Is called for a list of jobs in one time

```
results = pool.map(func, [1, 2, 3])
```

#### apply

Can only be called for one job

```
for x, y in [[1, 1], [2, 2]]:
    results.append(pool.apply(func, (x, y)))

def collect_result(result):
    results.append(result)
```

#### map_async

Is called for a list of jobs in one time

```
pool.map_async(func, jobs, callback=collect_result)
```

#### apply_async

Can only be called for one job and executes a job in the background in parallel

```
for x, y in [[1, 1], [2, 2]]:
    pool.apply_async(worker, (x, y), callback=collect_result)
```

#### starmap

Is a variant of `pool.map` which support multiple arguments

```
pool.starmap(func, [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)])
```

#### starmap_async

A combination of starmap() and map_async() that iterates over iterable of iterables and calls func with the iterables unpacked. Returns a result object.

```
pool.starmap_async(calculate_worker, [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)], callback=collect_result)
```

## Reference:

Find complete documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Pool.starmap() is blocking

Comment: I like this answer, +1

Comment: if apply does not have concurrence, then what is its point? use?

Comment: A table/picture is worth a thousand words, I always come back to this answer again and again to pick the function I want.

Comment: This is all very nice in theory, but in practice you often have to very carefully tune the size of work delegated to each parallel worker in order to get any speedup in the face of all of the overheads involved in using the pool. In particular you have to be using shared memory rather than passing the arguments and the return values directly, to avoid the serialization time of them between your main process and the workers when they are large. Otherwise it's no more than a  way of warming yourself up through hardware heat dissipation on a cold day.

Answer (score 90):

Regarding `apply` vs `map`:

`pool.apply(f, args)`: `f` is only executed in ONE of the workers of the pool. So ONE of the processes in the pool will run `f(args)`.

`pool.map(f, iterable)`: This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. So you take advantage of all the processes in the pool.

Comment: what if the iterable is a generator

Comment: Hmm... Good question. To be honest I haven't ever used pools with generators, but this thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318936/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration

Comment: @kakhkAtion  Regarding apply, if only one of the workers execute the function, what do the rest of the workers do? Do I have to call apply multiple times to have the rest of the workers perform a task?

Comment: True. Also take a look at pool.apply_async if you want to lunch workers asynchronously. "pool_apply blocks until the result is ready, so apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel"

Comment: What happens when I have 4 processes but have called `apply_async()` 8 times? Will it automatically handle it with a queue?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran When I tested it using map() function, I think it works as you said. I put 13 arguments in one iterable and run it with 12 core. 12 jobs were running simultaneously and the rest one works after the first bunch is done.