# Python multiprocessing: How to know to use Pool or Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

So I have an algorithm I am writing, and the function `multiprocess` is supposed to call another function, `CreateMatrixMp()`, on as many processes as there are cpus, in parallel. I have never done multiprocessing before, and cannot be certain which one of the below methods is more efficient. The word "efficient" being used in the context of the function `CreateMatrixMp()` needing to potentially be called thousands of times.I have read all of the documentation on the python `multiprocessing` module, and have come to these two possibilities:

First is using the `Pool` class:

```
def MatrixHelper(self, args):
    return self.CreateMatrix(*args)

def Multiprocess(self, sigmaI, sigmaX):

    cpus = mp.cpu_count()
    print('Number of cpu\'s to process WM: %d' % cpus)
    poolCount = cpus*2
    args = [(sigmaI, sigmaX, i) for i in range(self.numPixels)]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes = poolCount, maxtasksperchild= 2)
    tempData = pool.map(self.MatrixHelper, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And next is using the `Process` class:

```
def Multiprocess(self, sigmaI, sigmaX):

    cpus = mp.cpu_count()
    print('Number of cpu\'s to process WM: %d' % cpus)

    processes = [mp.Process(target = self.CreateMatrixMp, args = (sigmaI, sigmaX, i,)) for i in range(self.numPixels)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

`Pool` seems to be the better choice. I have read that it causes less overhead. And `Process` does not consider the number of cpus on the machine. The only problem is that using `Pool` in this manner gives me error after error, and whenever I fix one, there is a new one underneath it. `Process` seems easier to implement, and for all I know it may be the better choice. What does your experience tell you?

If `Pool` should be used, then am I right in choosing `map()`? It would be preferred that order is maintained. I have `tempData = pool.map(...)` because the `map` function is supposed to return a list of the results of every process. I am not sure how `Process` handles its returned data.

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176178/python-multiprocessing-process-or-pool-for-what-i-am-doing

Thanks

Comment: @MartinAlderete I have read that post. However, I ask some different questions here that need answering. He is using two target functions while I am using one, he passes no arguments while I pass multiple, and he does not have to be concerned with his target being an instance method, as mine is. I have done a lot of research on this so far, and both `Pool` and `Process` seem to behave differently under different contexts, and it certainly seems that one would be better in certain situations, while in others it wouldn't. I thought it appropriate to start a new question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the `Pool` class is typically more convenient, but it depends whether you want your results ordered or unordered.

Say you want to create 4 random strings (e.g,. could be a random user ID generator or so):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
               for i in range(length))
    output.put(rand_str)

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(5, output)) for x in range(4)]

# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
results = [output.get() for p in processes]

print(results)

# Output
# ['yzQfA', 'PQpqM', 'SHZYV', 'PSNkD']
```

Here, the order probably doesn't matter. I am not sure if there is a better way to do it, but if I want to keep track of results in the order in which the functions are called, I typically return tuples with an ID as first item, e.g.,

```
# define a example function
def rand_string(length, pos, output):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
                for i in range(length))
    output.put((pos, rand_str))

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(5, x, output)) for x in range(4)]

print(processes)

# Output
# [(1, '5lUya'), (3, 'QQvLr'), (0, 'KAQo6'), (2, 'nj6Q0')]
```

This let's me sort the results then:

```
results.sort()
results = [r[1] for r in results]
print(results)

# Output:
# ['KAQo6', '5lUya', 'nj6Q0', 'QQvLr']
```

### The Pool class

Now to your question: How is this different from the `Pool` class?
You'd typically prefer `Pool.map` to return ordered list of results without going through the hoop of creating tuples and sorting them by ID. Thus, I would say it is typically more efficient.

```
def cube(x):
    return x**3

pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
results = pool.map(cube, range(1,7))
print(results)

# output:
# [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
```

Equivalently, there is also an "apply" method:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
results = [pool.apply(cube, args=(x,)) for x in range(1,7)]
print(results)

# output:
# [1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]
```

Both `Pool.apply` and `Pool.map` will lock the main program until a process has finished.

Now, you also have `Pool.apply_async` and `Pool.map_async`, which return the result as soon as the process has finished, which is essentially similar to the `Process` class above. The advantage may be that they provide you with the convenient `apply` and `map` functionality that you know from Python's in-built `apply` and `map`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My main concern in choosing one over the other is the consideration of the machines number of processors. In Pool, you can set it so that there are the same number of processes as cpus. But by using `Process`, the number of cpus comes in nowhere. Will this be handled on its own? Will it result in slightly more time to go through by using `Process`? I would like to use `Process`, and `Pool` is giving me a very hard time with all of its pickle errors, but `Process` just doesn't feel concrete enough like `Pool` does.

Comment: I think "Process" is more of a "bare bones" approach, as far as I know, you'd have to manage it manually. When you spawn a process but all CPUs are busy, it will be queued until a CPU becomes free again. This could potentially be a problem if you are dispatching too many processes at once which are waiting (it could easily eat up your system's available memory if the number is "relatively" large)

Comment: Yes, the memory was a problem when trying to use `Process`. I have gotten it to work with `Pool`, thank you for your advice, I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with [pypeln](https://github.com/cgarciae/pypeln/):

```py
import pypeln as pl

stage = pl.process.map(
    CreateMatrixMp, 
    range(self.numPixels), 
    workers=poolCount, 
    maxsize=2,
)

# iterate over it in the main process
for x in stage:
   # code

# or convert it to a list
data = list(stage)
```