# Python Multiprocessing: pool.map vs using queues

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am trying to use the `multiprocessing` package for `Python`. In looking at tutorials, the clearest and most straightforward technique seems to be using `pool.map`, which allows the user to easily name the number of processes and pass `pool.map` a function and a list of values for that function to distribute across the CPUs. The other technique that I have come across is [using queues](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/) to manage a pool of workers. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533626/2327821) does an excellent job explaining the difference between `pool.map`, `pool.apply`, and `pool.apply_async`, but what are the advantages and disadvantages of using `pool.map` versus using queues like in this [example](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2008/nov/11/brief-introduction-multiprocessing/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `pool.map` technique is a "subset" of the technique with queues. That is, without having `pool.map` you can easily implement it using `Pool` and `Queue`. That said, using queues gives you much more flexibility in controlling your pool processes, i.e. you can make it so that particular types of messages are read only once per processes' lifetime, control the pool processes' shutdown behaviour, etc.

Comment: Does `pool.map` automatically shut down the processes when it completes?

Comment: From the docs: ``When the pool object is garbage collected terminate() will be called immediately.``. But i wouldn't rely on it - it'd better if you had ensured the pool has closed at the end of your app. Otherwise, you might end up with some zombies left in your system. As for `pool.map` - no, it doesn't shut down the processes. The processes live as long as their pool unless closed or orphaned.

Answer (score 4):

If you're really looking for the "clearest and most straightforward technique", using [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) is probably the easiest way. It has a `map` method as well as some other primitives that make it very usable. It is also compatible with `Queue`s.

Comment: very easy and intuitive library.