# Multiprocess itertool combination with two arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have the following function that I would like to run using multiprocessing:

```
def bruteForcePaths3(paths, availableNodes):

    results = []

    #start by taking each combination 2 at a time, then 3, etc
    for i in range(1,len(availableNodes)+1):
        print "combo number: %d" % i

        currentCombos = combinations(availableNodes, i)

        for combo in currentCombos:
            #get a fresh copy of paths for this combiniation
            currentPaths = list(paths)
            currentRemainingPaths = []
            # print combo

            for node in combo:
                #determine better way to remove nodes, for now- if it's in, we remove
                currentRemainingPaths = [path for path in currentPaths if not (node in path)]
                currentPaths = currentRemainingPaths

            #if there are no paths left
            if len(currentRemainingPaths) == 0:
                #save this combination
                print combo
                results.append(frozenset(combo))

    return results
```

Bases on a few other post ([Combining itertools and multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306522/combining-itertools-and-multiprocessing)), I tried to multiprocess this by the following:

```
def grouper_nofill(n, iterable):
        it=iter(iterable)
        def take():
            while 1: yield list(islice(it,n))
        return iter(take().next,[])

    def mp_bruteForcePaths(paths, availableNodes):

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        chunksize=256
        async_results=[]


        def worker(paths,combos, out_q):
            """ The worker function, invoked in a process. 'nums' is a
                list of numbers to factor. The results are placed in
                a dictionary that's pushed to a queue.
            """
            results = bruteForcePaths2(paths, combos)
            print results
            out_q.put(results)


        for i in range(1,len(availableNodes)+1):
            currentCombos = combinations(availableNodes, i)
            for finput in grouper_nofill(chunksize,currentCombos):

                args = (paths, finput)
                async_results.extend(pool.map_async(bruteForcePaths2, args).get())

                print async_results

    def bruteForcePaths2(args):
        paths, combos = args
        results = []

        for combo in combos:
            #get a fresh copy of paths for this combiniation
            currentPaths = list(paths)
            currentRemainingPaths = []
            # print combo

            for node in combo:
                #determine better way to remove nodes, for now- if it's in, we remove
                currentRemainingPaths = [path for path in currentPaths if not (combo in path)]
                currentPaths = currentRemainingPaths

            #if there are no paths left
            if len(currentRemainingPaths) == 0:
                #save this combination
                print combo
                results.append(frozenset(combo))

        return results
```

I need to be able to pass in 2 arguments to the bruteforce function. I'm getting the error:
"too many values to unpack"

So 3 part question:
How can I multiprocess the bruteforce function over nproc cpu's splitting the combinations iterator?
How can I pass in the two arguments- path and combinations?
How do I get the result (think the mpa_async should do that for me)?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Python's map\_async keeping results in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690517/how-is-pythons-map-async-keeping-results-in-order)

Comment: You can use `def bruteForcePaths2(*args):` for multiple parameters

Comment: that thread uses a list as an argument, not itertool. The issue with using the itertool is getting the length and/or not having the whole itertool consumed on the first call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
args = (paths, finput)
pool.map_async(bruteForcePaths2, args)
```

makes these two calls, which is not your intent:

```
bruteForcePaths2(paths)
bruteForcePaths2(finput)
```

You can use `apply_async` instead to submit single function calls to the pool. Note also that if you call `get` immediately it will wait for the result, and you don't get any advantage from multiprocessing.

You could do it like this:

```
for i in range(1,len(availableNodes)+1):
    currentCombos = combinations(availableNodes, i)
    for finput in grouper_nofill(chunksize,currentCombos):

        args = (paths, finput)
        async_results.append(pool.apply_async(bruteForcePaths2, args))

results = [x.get() for x in async_results]
```