# map_async vs apply_async:what should I use in this case

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am processing some ascii-data, make some operations, and then writing everything back to another file (job done by `post_processing_0.main`, without returning anything). I want to parallelize the code with the multiprocessing module, see the following code snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import post_processing_0

def chunks(lst,n):
    return [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n) ]

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=proc_num)
    P={}
    for i in range(0,proc_num):
        P['process_'+str(i)]=pool.apply_async(post_processing_0.main, [split_list[i]])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


proc_num=8
timesteps=100
list_to_do=range(0,timesteps)
split_list=chunks(list_to_do,proc_num)

main()
```

I read the difference between map and async, but I don t understand it very well. Is my application of multiprocessing module correct?

In this case, should I use map_async or apply_async? And why?

Edit:

I don't think this is a duplicate of the question [Python multiprocessing.Pool: when to use apply, apply_async or map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/python-multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map). In the question, the answer focus on the order of the result that can be obtained using the two functions. Here i am asking: what is it the difference when nothing is returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing.Pool: when to use apply, apply\_async or map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/python-multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map)

Comment: I read that question, but it doesn't clear my doubts. I am asking a stricter question: what is the difference in this case, where no result from the parallelized function is returned, ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend `map_async` for three reasons:

1. It's cleaner looking code. This:

   ```
   pool = Pool(processes=proc_num)
   async_result = pool.map_async(post_processing_0.main, split_list)
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   ```

   looks nicer than this:

   ```
   pool = Pool(processes=proc_num)
   P={}
   for i in range(0,proc_num):
       P['process_'+str(i)]=pool.apply_async(post_processing_0.main, [split_list[i]])
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   ```
2. With `apply_async`, if an exception occurs inside of `post_processing_0.main`, you won't know about it unless you explicitly call `P['process_x'].get()` on the failing `AsyncResult` object, which would require iterating over all of `P`. With `map_async` the exception will be raised if you call `async_result.get()` - no iteration required.
3. `map_async` has built-in chunking functionality, which will make your code perform noticeably better if `split_list` is very large.

Other than that, the behavior is basically the same if you don't care about the results.

Answer (score 15):

`apply_async` submits a single job to the pool.  `map_async` submits multiple jobs calling the same function with different arguments.  The former takes a function plus argument list; the latter takes a function plus iterable (i.e. sequence) which represents the arguments.  `map_async` can only call unary functions (i.e. functions taking one argument).

In your case, it might be better to restructure the code slightly to put all your arguments in a single list and just call `map_async` once with that list.

Comment: So if we consider 4 processes and 16  file to postprocess, map will "create" 16 instances that will run all at the same time?

Comment: You mean the pool has size 4 and the arguments list has size 16?  In that case, only 4 at a time will run; when the first completes, the fifth will start, etc.

Comment: Ok! Then i understand there are no differences(apart of modifying the code).is that correct?

Comment: I said what the differences are in my answer.  For example, `map_async` can only call unary functions.

Comment: Whereas other answers I read on SO still left me with questions, this answer clarified the difference between "apply_async" and "map_async" in a beautifully succinct way. Thank you!