# Callback not getting called

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, callback

```
for x,y in my_dict.iteritems():
     for z in y:
           def done_callback(result):

                code,content=result.get()
                if code==0:
                      if content:
                             new_content.append(content)
                      else:
                             pass
                else:
                      return error_html(environ,start_response,content)


           try:
                    pool.apply_async(function_returns_tuple,(x,z,my_val),done_callback)
           except Exception as e:
                    print e
```

When I see the value of new_content, it is empty and also callback function - done_callback is not getting called. Am I missing out on some part?

Comment: "When I see the value of new_content" is never shown in the code, and it is relevant to the question. But it seems like the typical async problem. Remember - any results from async should only ever be accessed from the callback (or somewhere where callback is in the stack trace). You might like using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to manage async for you.

Comment: new_content is just a list which I check outside of all this, outside of all the for loops.

Comment: Then it is as I predicted. Say you have four children; you tell them "I need to go to work, but my phone is missing, so everyone search, and give it to me when you find it!" and then, instead of waiting, *you go to work immediately*. One of your children finds the phone, then tries to give it to you, but you're not there any more. Meanwhile, you're at work, phoneless, wondering why kids are so lazy these days.

Comment: so how to fix it so that parent and children in sync? Note : python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working minimal example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

my_dict = { "a": [1, 2], "b": [3] }
my_val = 5

# has to be defined before Pool is created
def processing_function(args):
    (x, y, v) = args     # mapped function only gets one arg; so we unpack
    if y == 2:           # we throw a wrinkle in,
        return ('', '')  # to demonstrate filter
    return ("[Code %s %d %d]" % (x, y, v), "[Content %s %d %d]" % (x, y, v))


pool = Pool(2)    # execute two workers in parallel (feel free to change)

# make an iterator for all your values
inputs = ((x, z, my_val) for (x, y) in my_dict.iteritems() for z in y)
async_results = pool.map_async(processing_function, inputs)
pool.close()      # necessary before pool.join()
pool.join()       # wait for all processes in the pool to finish
results = async_results.get()    # now we can get the results
# we can extract just the results we want...
non_empty_content_joined = ''.join(
        content for (code, content) in results if content != '')
print non_empty_content_joined
# => [Content a 1 5][Content b 3 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example but what part is missing in my piece of code.Could you please point out loop holes in my excerpt?

Comment: `join()` will wait for the results in the main thread, if you need them in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a callback function in `apply_async`, the callback will be invoked at some later time. The 'async' part means you can continue going about your business on the current thread before the `apply`'d job has completed.

In your example code, you are calling `apply_async` in a loop but then you are not waiting for any of the operations to complete. You'll have to keep the main thread around (e.g., by blocking or looping) if you want to wait for the operations to complete.