# How to assign callback inside own class using python multiprocessing pool apply_async function

Tags: python, parameters, callback, multiprocessing

I tried to use multithread pool as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533626/4510954) question. But I want pack all logic to my own class as below. The problem occures in `apply_async` callback function. When I pack all logic in class, callback function seems to never be called. I do not know how to assign callback functions so that it will be called correctly. In source question there is only `result` in `log_result` parameters but I must add additional `self` parameters.

```
import numpy 
import pandas as pd 
import multiprocessing as mp 
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

class MutliThread() :
    def __init__(self):
        self.result_list = []

    def foo_pool(index, number):
        data = []
        notFound = []
        try :        
            data.append(index + number)
        except Exception:
            notFound.append(index + number)    
        return data

    def log_result(self, result):
        # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
        # result_list is modified only by the main process, not the pool workers.
        self.result_list.append(self, result)

    def apply_async_with_callback(self):
        pool = mp.Pool()
        data = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        for index, tarrif in enumerate(data) :
            pool.apply_async(self.foo_pool, args = (index, tarrif), callback = self.log_result)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(self.result_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    multiThread = MutliThread()
    multiThread.apply_async_with_callback()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback in your example is not called, because the tasks fail. An `error_callback` would be called with a `TypeError` for each of the tasks: `foo_pool() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

You either have to make `foo_pool` a normal method by adding `self` as the first parameter ...

```
def foo_pool(self, index, number):
```

... or by decorating it with `@staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def foo_pool(index, number):
```

Fixing this will cause `log_result` to fail, because you call `list.append` with two arguments while it only takes one.

Either wrap `self` and `result` in a data structure, e.g. a tuple ...

```
self.result_list.append((self, result))
```

... or skip appending `self` alltogether. In the end this is always going to be your `MultiThread` instance:

```
self.result_list.append(result)
```

The name `MultiThread` is misleading by the way. Your class wraps a process pool, not a thread pool.