# how to ensure multiprocessing code using the configured cpu cores?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, hpc

I use `multiprocessing Pool` to run `parallel`. I tried with `4` cores first in `HPC` with sub. When it uses 4 core, the time is reduced 4 times compared to 1 core. When I check with `qstat`, several times it uses 4 cores but after that just 1 core, with exactly the same code.

Could you please give some advice what is wrong with my code or the system?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from datetime import datetime

t1 = pd.read_csv("template.csv",header=None)

s1 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_adfr.csv")
s2 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_dock.csv")
s3 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_gemdock.csv")
s4 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_ledock.csv")
s5 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_plants.csv")
s6 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_psovina.csv")
s7 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_quickvina2.csv")
s8 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_smina.csv")
s9 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_vina.csv")
s10 = pd.read_csv("/home/donp/dude_1000_raw_raw/dude_1000_raw_raw_vinaxb.csv")

#number of core and arrays

n = 4
m = (len(t1) // n)+1
g= m*n - len(t1)
for g1 in range(g):
    t1.loc[len(t1)]=0


results=[]

def block_linear(i):

    temp = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((m,29)))

    for a in range(0,m):
        sum_matrix = (t1.iloc[a,0]*s1) + (t1.iloc[a,1]*s2) + (t1.iloc[a,2]*s3)+ (t1.iloc[a,3]*s4) + (t1.iloc[a,4]*s5) + (t1.iloc[a,5]*s6) + (t1.iloc[a,6]*s7) + (t1.iloc[a,7]*s8) + (t1.iloc[a,8]*s9) + (t1.iloc[a,9]*s10)
        rank_sum= pd.DataFrame.rank(sum_matrix,axis=0,ascending=True,method='min') #real-True
        temp.iloc[a,:] = rank_sum.iloc[999].values
    temp['median'] = temp.median(axis=1)
    temp.index = range(i*m,(i+1)*m)
    return temp

start=datetime.now()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=n)
    results = pool.map(block_linear,range(0,n))

print(datetime.now()-start)

out=pd.concat(results)
out.drop(out.tail(g).index,inplace=True)
out.to_csv('test_10dock_4core.csv',index=False)
```

The main idea is to cut large table into smallers, run calculations and combine together.

Comment: What code?  You've shown nothing useful.

Comment: I have added the code. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Without a more detailed usage of the multiprocessing's Pool package is really difficult to understand and help. Please notice that the Pool package does not guarantee parallelization: the *_apply* function, for example, only uses one worker of the Pool, and block all your executions. You can check out more details about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map) and [there](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

But assuming you are using the library properly, you should make sure your code is fully parallelizable: an I/O operation on disk, for example, can bottleneck your parallelization and thus making your code run in only one process at a time.

I hope it helped.

---

[Edit]
Since you provided more details about your problem, I can give more specific tips:

The first thing is that your code is zero parallel. You are just calling the same function N times. This is not how multiprocessing should work.
Instead, the part that should be parallel is the one that is usually in a *for* loops, like the one you have inside the block_linear().

So, what I recommend to you:

You should change your code to first calculate all your weighted sum and only after that do the rest of the operations. This will help a lot with parallelization.
So, put this operation in a function:

```
  def weighted_sum(column,df2):
    temp = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(m))
    for a in range(0,m):
        result = (t1.iloc[a,column]*df2)
        temp.iloc[a] = result
    return temp
```

So then, you use pool.starmap to parallel the function for the 10 dataframes you have, something like this:

results = pool.starmap(weighted_sum,[(0,s1),(1,s2),(2,s3),....,[9,s10]])

ps: *pool.starmap* is similar to *pool.map* but accepts a list of tuple arguments. You can have more details about it [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap).

At last but not least, you should operate over your results to end your calculations. Since you will have one weighted_sum per column, you can apply a sum over the columns and then the rank_sum.

This is not a fully runnable code to solve your problem, but a general guide of how your should restructure your code to have a multiprocessing advantage. I recommend you to test it over a subsample of the data frames just to make sure it's working properly before you run it on all your data.

Comment: Thanks @Jean Américo. I have updated my code. Could you please have a look again?