# How come multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager is this slow on linux?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I'm trying to diagnose a performance problem with the server created by `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager`. The problem boils down to this:

`server.py`:

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers

auth_key = b'12345678901234567890'
port = 32001

shared_values = {}

def _shared_values():
    global shared_values
    return shared_values

class SharedStateManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager): pass

SharedStateManager.register('SharedValues', callable=_shared_values)

multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = auth_key
server = SharedStateManager(address=('', port), authkey=auth_key)

server.get_server().serve_forever()
```

`client.py`:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.managers

auth_key = b'12345678901234567890'
port = 32001

class SharedStateManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager): pass

SharedStateManager.register('SharedValues')

multiprocessing.current_process().authkey = auth_key
ssm = SharedStateManager(address=('', port), authkey=auth_key)

cl1 = time.time_ns()
ssm.connect()
cl2 = time.time_ns()
shared_values = ssm.SharedValues()
cl3 = time.time_ns()
print('2-1: {} ms'.format((cl2 - cl1) / (10 ** 6)))
print('3-2: {} ms'.format((cl3 - cl2) / (10 ** 6)))
```

When I run the client code on a Debian buster instance running on Intel 8th-gen 2.3GHz i5 with 4 cores, I get:

```
2-1: 42.124515 ms
3-2: 132.311978 ms
```

Which is very slow. The python version is 3.7.3 although I tried different version with docker containers and got similar results.

But if I run the same code on a Macbook (macos 11.6) that has a similar CPU, I get:

```
2-1: 1.950359 ms
3-2: 3.264376 ms
```

What might be the cause of such dramatic response time difference?

Edit: The target machine isn't broken or anything. It's running a couple of QEMU virtual machines plus a few docker containers. So far the network latency did not happen on for instance, a [sanic](https://sanicframework.org/en/) based HTTP server or other containerized socket servers. Copying a file over a network share will max out the LAN at about 100MB/s. So it's happening to Python's multiprocessing server in particular.

Edit: I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805160/the-different-performance-of-python-multiprocessing-pool-on-macos-and-linux-syst) which sort of exhibited the same behavior regarding a Python multiprocessing program running much faster on mac than linux.

Edit: **Solved!** I thought I was running Debian bullseye but it turned out I was running buster. After exhausting all other options I gave release upgrade a try. And the latency went away after the upgrade.

Comment: Running ubuntu on a notebook with i5 CPU @ 1.6 GHz, I got  `2-1: 0.935857 ms,
 3-2: 1.735488 ms`. So, its not linux in general.

Comment: Wild speculation - you could see if using the loopback address (usually 127.0.0.1) instead of `''` makes a difference. loopback should bypass much of the network stack. I'd be surprised if that's it, though.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks. Though the change of IP binding didn't do anything. It could be a network config problem but I'm not sure how to debug.