# TypeError("predictions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'solvent'") while using celery

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

I am doing inference on two strings using celery and django rest framework but I am getting error while using `.delay()` or `apply_async()`. I am not getting the predicted response

```py
#views.py
@api_view(['GET'])
def result(request):
    response = {}
    solute = request.GET.get('solute')
    solvent = request.GET.get('solvent')
    results = predictions.apply_async(args=(solute,solvent))
    print(results.get())
    return Response({'result': results.get()}, status=200)
```

```py
#tasks.py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def predictions(self,solute, solvent):

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solute)
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
    solute = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    solute_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solute)

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solvent)
    mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
    solvent = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    solvent_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solvent)
```

I am getting problems while adding `apply_async or delay()` to predictions.
I am getting `TypeError("predictions() missing 1 required positional argument: 'solvent'")` Error

Answer (score 1):

mainly:

> apply_async(func: Callable[..., Any],args:Iterable[Any] etc)

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533318/multiprocessing-pool-when-to-use-apply-apply-async-or-map)

Comment: Is it `requests` or `request`? using `request` I am getting `AttributeError at /predict/
'Request' object has no attribute 'get'` Error @Mahamudul Hasan

Comment: using `requests` i am getting `NameError at /predict/
name 'requests' is not defined` Error