# Python multiprocessing: how to limit the number of waiting processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

When running a large number of tasks (with large parameters) using Pool.apply_async, the processes are allocated and go to a waiting state, and there is no limit for the number of waiting processes. This can end up by eating all memory, as in the example below:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def f(a,b):
    return np.linalg.solve(a,b)

def test():

    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for _ in range(1000):
        p.apply_async(f, (np.random.rand(1000,1000),np.random.rand(1000)))
    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

I'm searching for a way to limit the waiting queue, in such a way that there is only a limited number of waiting processes, and Pool.apply_async is blocked while the waiting queue is full.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Pool` has a `_taskqueue` member of type `multiprocessing.Queue`, which takes an optional `maxsize` parameter; unfortunately it constructs it without the `maxsize` parameter set.

I'd recommend subclassing `multiprocessing.Pool` with a copy-paste of `multiprocessing.Pool.__init__` that passes `maxsize` to `_taskqueue` constructor.

Monkey-patching the object (either the pool or the queue) would also work, but you'd have to monkeypatch `pool._taskqueue._maxsize` and `pool._taskqueue._sem` so it would be quite brittle:

```
pool._taskqueue._maxsize = maxsize
pool._taskqueue._sem = BoundedSemaphore(maxsize)
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3, and the _taskqueue is of type Queue.Queue. It means it is a simple Queue, and not a multiprocessing.Queue. Subclassing multiprocessing.Pool and overriding __init__ works fine, but monkey-patching the object is not working as expected. However, this is the hack that I was searching for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wait if `pool._taskqueue` is over the desired size:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

import numpy as np


def f(a,b):
    return np.linalg.solve(a,b)

def test(max_apply_size=100):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for _ in range(1000):
        p.apply_async(f, (np.random.rand(1000,1000),np.random.rand(1000)))

        while p._taskqueue.qsize() > max_apply_size:
            time.sleep(1)

    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Just want to add that I found this to be the easiest solution to my memory problems with multiprocessing. I used max_apply_size = 10 and that works fine for my problem, which is a slow file conversion. Using a semaphore as @ecatmur suggests seems like a more robust solution but might be overkill for simple scripts.

Comment: TaylorMonacelli That your edits were rejected exemplifies the problems with mods on SO. Your edit fixed a bug. @greg-449 is a "drive-by-mod", approves only 15% of edits and gave a nonsensical reason for the rejection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a monkey patching alternative to the top answer:

```
import queue
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool


class PatchedQueue():
  """
  Wrap stdlib queue and return a Queue(maxsize=...)
  when queue.SimpleQueue is accessed
  """

  def __init__(self, simple_queue_max_size=5000):
    self.simple_max = simple_queue_max_size  

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr == "SimpleQueue":
      return lambda: queue.Queue(maxsize=self.simple_max)
    return getattr(queue, attr)


class BoundedPool(Pool):
  # Override queue in this scope to use the patcher above
  queue = PatchedQueue()

pool = BoundedPool()
pool.apply_async(print, ("something",))
```

This is working as expected for Python 3.8 where multiprocessing Pool is using `queue.SimpleQueue` to setup the task queue. It sounds like the implementation for `multiprocessing.Pool` may have changed since 2.7

Comment: I didn't test the ThreadPool one, but if I modify it to `from multiprocessing.pool import Pool`, it does not work (the limit is not changed, and it seems that the `SimpleQueue` is not being changed to `Queue`). Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add explicit Queue with maxsize parameter and use `queue.put()` instead of `pool.apply_async()` in this case. Then worker processes could:

```
for a, b in iter(queue.get, sentinel):
    # process it
```

If you want to limit the number of created input arguments/results that are in memory to approximately the number of active worker processes then you could use `pool.imap*()` methods:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def f(a_b):
    return np.linalg.solve(*a_b)

def main():
    args = ((np.random.rand(1000,1000), np.random.rand(1000))
            for _ in range(1000))
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for result in p.imap_unordered(f, args, chunksize=1):
        pass
    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Using `imap` makes no difference. The input queue is still unlimited and using this solution will end up eating all memory.

Comment: @Radim: the `imap` code in the answer works even if you give it an infinite generator.

Comment: Not in Python 2, unfortunately (haven't looked at code in py3). For some work arounds, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318936/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration).