# Python 2 multiprocessing map without exhausting generator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a generator that downloads files from FTP. I want to run these in parallel, without exhausting the generator together. I want the generator to lazily be evaluated. Is this possible in Python 2?

```
    def parse_and_load(filename):
        raw_records, exchange_data = parser.parse(filename)
        loader.load(raw_records, exchange_data)

    with closing(mp.Pool(4)) as pool:
        pool.map(parse_and_load, downloader.get_files(self.date))
```

Instead of downloading 4 files and processing them in parallel, the above code is evaluating the whole generator first and then calling parse and load in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**EDIT**] Sorry, I've spoken too soon.

The same problem is discussed in [Python Multiprocessing.Pool lazy iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318936/python-multiprocessing-pool-lazy-iteration). It points out that is by design of `multiprocessing.map`. Getting a lazier behaviour will require changing tools. Some suggestions:

- use `pool.apply_async` coupled with a `Queue` to submit a new job once one is finished
- use NuMap, as suggested [in this answer of the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24302211/7002298)

So if I understood well, the below solution is not relevant for the OP question.

---

You're probably getting bitten by the `chunksize` argument (see [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)). 
What happens under the hood is that `multiprocessing` "groups" arguments into chunks to limit inter-process overheads.

You should try again with `chunksize=1`